# libjpeg wrong version error

Tags: c, libjpeg

I am trying to use libjpeg to decompress a jpeg contained in a memory block into its RGB values. I originally had version 6.2 on my system, but I needed the function jpeg_mem_src so I upgraded to 8d. I use the follow commands to install/configure:

```
./configure
sudo make clean
sudo make
sudo make uninstall
sudo make install
```

And to compile my program I use (discounting the commands to remove .o files and recompile them):

```
g++ main.o googlestreetview.o -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lcurl -ltinyxml2 -ljpeg -o example
```

However when running this code:

```
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error( &jerr );
jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
```

I simply get: "Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80"

This seems strange, because I have not only manually removed libjpeg from my system, but I've recompiled 8d and installed it a number of times. What steps can I take to resolve this?

Comment: This is usually caused by mismatched libjpeg headers and libraries. Do you have any *old* copies of the libjpeg header files anywhere? If so, remove them.

Comment: My guess is that my headers are the right version (80) and my library is the wrong version (62), however I have scoured my machine for libjpeg libraries to purge, recompiled and reinstalled them and still no change. I'm at a loss as to where it's hiding.

Comment: Dynamic libraries stay in RAM if anything has loaded them.  Rebooting will fix this.

Comment: Rebooted, issue is still prevalent. Even more irksome is the binary refuses to load if I delete the libraries, and if I rebuild the library and manually check the binary in a hex editor for some strings I added they are there. Is there anyway to check exactly where the binary is loading libjpeg from?

Comment: Try showing us the output of the compile after adding `-v` to the compile command, and if it's really C code, then use `gcc` or `cc` _NOT_ _ever_ `g++`!  FYI, dynamic libraries _DO NOT_ "stay in RAM" in any sense that will affect running a program a second time -- at least not on any sanely implemented system.

Comment: The code is a C API that uses C++ in its implementation but not in its interface (hence the use of g++). The -v output for the compilation is http://pastebin.com/qbHbWsjF

Answer (score 0):

try

```
./configure --with-jpeg8
```

before to recompile it.